# Remove comma from jspinner

Tags: java, swing, input, jspinner

Is there anyway to remove the comma from the Jspinner, i'm trying to use it as input for the year but it displays 2011 as 2,011. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set the spinner to use a [`SpinnerDateModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SpinnerDateModel.html).

Answer (score 13):

I think this is an easier solution :

```
JSpinner.NumberEditor editor = new JSpinner.NumberEditor(mySpinner, "#");
mySpinner.setEditor(editor);
```

Comment: +1 Allows more flexibility (if you're interested in something besides years; e.g., port number, etc.). Docs: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JSpinner.NumberEditor.html

Answer (score 2):

Or you can do these in Netbeans in few clicks.

select the jspinner component (the one you dragged)

> > properties >> editor >> change the type to Number and format to 0000.

:D

Comment: -1 a) always use the most appropriate type (which is not Number here) b) no need to use a particular IDE

Comment: Always provide actual code help please, IDE-specific tools aren't an answer.

Comment: Sometimes people need IDE specific answers - like me right now - for homework, where we can't use code. Hate NetBeans too by the way. +1

Answer (score 0):

```
JSpinner.NumberEditor editor = new JSpinner.NumberEditor( spinner, "#" );
spinner.setEditor( editor );
```

Hope this will help  you.

Comment: Your answer is no different than Brad's answer above.